# Time graph of non-numeric data

Tags: excel, graph, excel-2007

I'm trying to draw a scatter-plot in Excel 2007, with times along the x-axis, and text values along the y-axis.  Since I can build numeric values for the y-axis, another possible way to look at this would be to change the labels along the y-axis to be text (instead of their default numeric values).

My actual dataset looks something like this:

```
start, end, flag, value
1:00am, 2:30am, 0, A
2:30am, 7:00am, 3, D
7:00am, 12:30pm, 2, C
12:30pm, 4:00pm, 7, H
```

Generally, if I were to plot this, I would translate it to something like:

```
time, flag, value
1:00am, 0, A
2:30am, 0, A
2:30am, 3, D
7:00am, 3, D
7:00am, 2, C
12:30pm, 2, C
12:30pm, 7, H
4:00pm, 7, H
```

Then I would build a scatter-plot with the time column as the x-axis and the flag column as the y-axis.  However, I'd much rather have the value column provide the label on the y-axis.

I can't seem to find a way to do this in Excel.

Am I missing something or is there another tool I should look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about a close I can manage, with heavy reliance on [Jon Peltier](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/text-labels-on-vertical-axis-in-excel-column-chart/), of course:

[image: SO15746918 example]

I doubt it is good enough so I am not cluttering this 'answer' up with much detail. Even this poor offering was extremely fiddly so if an acceptable quality was even more so I think it likely most people would not consider that worth the effort.

The chart is a combination of a scatter plot that is visible and a bar chart whose axis only is visible, and the data was first sorted into alphabetical order. The data is paired, hence duplication of the letters) and a Gantt-type bar chart (showing duration rather than just start and finish) would make adding text labels for the vertical axis very much easier and neater.

Comment: while this may be a "hacky" solution, I think it will meet my needs!  This whole concept has been way more complicated than it should be...

Comment: an understandable question. A bar chart doesn't work because of the variable nature of the time lengths in the x-axis.  I'm trying to display the timeline of a system as it transitions between known states.  (Though admittedly, the scatter plot without lines doesn't make much sense)